# Loading data into DynamoDB table always throttles

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am quite new to DynamoDB and NodeJS, so I wanted to have a play with this. But I'm kinda getting thrown off a little bit when I tried to load data into a table.

I created a table which has 1 read capacity unit and 1 write capacity unit, and I've got a json dataset that contains 10,000 items. Each item contains only one key/value pair, so the size of an item is quite small, around 50 bytes or so. I have a simple function in NodeJS that reads the file, loop them through, and for each item, I call `putItem` api to write it to the dynamodb table.

When I run it, it all looked fine until some point, it started to throttle out requests. It keeps saying "provisioned throughput has been exceeded". Later I tried to up the write capacity unit to like 10000 (maximum), or even enable auto scaling, neither worked. The cloudwatch metric says the consumed write capacity is around 8 or something, but I can't figure out why that's the case. I just took the sample nodejs code from the AWS doc like following:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var fs = require('fs');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "ap-southeast-2",
    profile: "default"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Importing tokens into DynamoDB. Please wait.");

var allTokens = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('token.json', 'utf8'));
allTokens.forEach(function(token) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "NewToken",
        Item: {
            "token":  token.token,
        }
    };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add token", token.token, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", token.token);
       }
    });
});
```

The dataset looks like this

```
[
    {"token": "kmxgar0b91"},
    {"token": "pzbljf0s9q"},
    {"token": "24j052s72z"},
    {"token": "xg2b9s4tk7"},
    {"token": "g1268hs4re"},
    ....
]
```

The error I can see from running the script is like this:

```
Unable to add token vv8wtryxmz . Error JSON: {
  "message": "The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.",
  "code": "ProvisionedThroughputExceededException",
  "time": "2018-02-21T12:04:52.779Z",
  "requestId": "RE6UTK0RBM47VUSEBIUBIUTHBRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": true
}
```

Can anyone point out what might've gone wrong with my script or my configuration with dynamodb table?

Much appreciated.

Comment: As per AWS documentation: ```One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item up to 1 KB in size. If you need to write an item that is larger than 1 KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional write capacity units. The total number of write capacity units required depends on the item size.``` Can you try adding a `sleep` between each writes?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it in this case, but you could also be throttled by writing to a [hot partition](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/).

Comment: @mkobit Don't think so. The 10000 records have unique "token" attribute, which is also the partition key. And I am simply looping through them and write them by one by into the table.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR Yeah I can. But I am just wondering why it even happened after I enabled auto scaling. The max in auto scaling is 10000, I have 10000 records, so even 10000 records' writes were fired at the same time, the AS should capacity to handle that right?